# meteor apollo graphql/sequelize cache query results to avoid multiple identical queries

Tags: javascript, meteor, sequelize.js, graphql, apollo

I use Apollo/graphql/sequelize to grab the following relation:

I have multiple markers. Each has only one Style. Markers may use the same styles:

Sequelize:

```
var Marker = db.define('markers', {
  name: {type: Sequelize.TEXT},
  idstyle: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER},
}, {timestamps: false});
const Markers = db.models.markers;

var Style = db.define('styles', {
  name: {type: Sequelize.TEXT},
  icon: {type: Sequelize.TEXT}
}, {timestamps: false});

Marker.belongsTo(Style, {foreignKey: 'idstyle'});
```

graphql schema:

```
type Marker {
    id: Int
    name: String
    style: Style
}

type Style {
    id: Int
    name: String
    icon: String
}

type Query {
  marker(limit: Int, offset: Int): [Marker]
  style(limit: Int, offset: Int): [Style]
}
```

resolvers:

```
Query: {
        async marker(root, args, context) {
            return Markers.findAll({limit: args.limit, offset: args.offset});
        },
        async style(root, args, context) {
            return Styles.findAll({limit: args.limit, offset: args.offset});
        }
    },
    Marker: {
        async style(marker) {
            return marker.getStyle();
        }
    }
```

I realized that there does not seem to be any intelligent caching when I run the following query:

```
query{
  marker{
    name
    style{
      name
    }
  }
}
```

It seems that the same styles are queried again even when they have already been returned as a result for another marker. You can see that the requested style ids repeat:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use DataLoader:

https://github.com/facebook/dataloader

Here's an example use with Apollo:

https://github.com/apollostack/GitHunt-API/blob/106204c110980df28b70b565452a61648825d98b/api/github/connector.js